# Whats the meaning of "???" in ls command output

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, ntfs, ls

I am using WD my passport hard disk.

when i use `ll -l` command in my hard drive it shows as below

```
ls: cannot access The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E15.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E16.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E17.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access TV Seasons: No such file or directory



-????????? ? ?    ?            ?                ? The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E16.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4
-????????? ? ?    ?            ?                ? The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E17.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4
drwx------ 1 root root      8192 2014-06-24 08:36 The Big Bang Theory - The Complete Season 7 [HDTV]/
d????????? ? ?    ?            ?                ? TV Seasons/
```

chmod and chown command also does not work.

```
chmod 777  The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E07.HDTV.x264-LOL.\[VTV\].mp4 
chmod: cannot access `The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E07.HDTV.x264-LOL.[VTV].mp4': No such file or directory
```

How can i recover my files?  Partition of my drive is **NTFS.**

Comment: It seems files are corrupted , if you have Windows installed run `chkdsk` to check and fix errors.

Comment: Your files seem to have special NTFS permissions that are not supported in the standard Linux persmissions. I would be careful changing them in Linux because you can cause NTFS corruptions and render those files useless... Try and see if you can `sudo cp` those files to your Linux files systems and when you're back in Windows, change permissions back to standard ones. If you make them readable to everyone, you shouldn't have any problems in Linux with any account.

Comment: see my answer i have solved that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#Solved**

In Linux i could not do anything.

On Windows 7 laptop i have plugged my hard drive and pop up comes for

```
scan and fix
or 
Continue without scanning
```

I have clicked on scan and fix and then wait until it get finished. After that i can see all my corrupted files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Gparted software to fix your hard drive. Try either the live dvd or the software which can be found in software center.
http://gparted.org/